# R Nonlinear regression

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I need a help with a curve fitting problem. I am also quite new to R. I have some data ( 3 pairs of type `(x,y)`), and need to apply a Nonlinear regression.

Basically, I have  a function `f(x,a,b,c,d,e,f)` -  `x` and 6 other parameters. I want to find a set of `(a,b,c,d,e,f)` which minimizes
weighted sum of squared residuals (weights inversely proportional to squared standard deviations (though in other line it says inversely proportional to variances - maybe it is the same, don't know)).

Can this be done in a simple way on R? Or is there any other software which can do this in a simple manner?

Comment: Use the `nls` to do LS iterative fitting for non-linear functions.

Comment: If you have only three data points it is impossible to fit a six-parameter function.

Comment: I know that 3 is very little data as the answer is not likely to be unique. But I have to at least try something : )

Comment: You can try all you want, but it's mathematically impossible.